# How to create sine chorus effect in matlab

Tags: matlab, trigonometry, audioeffect

I'm trying to create the Sine Chorus effect in Matlab. This is my code :

```
function y=chorus(x, f_sine, delay, depth, mix, fs);
x=wavread(x);
BL=0.7;
FB=-0.7;
FF=1;

for n=1:length(x);
M(n)=delay+depth*(0.5+0.5*sin(2*pi*f_sine*n/fs)); 
xh=x(n)+FB*xh(n-M(n));
y(n)=FF*xh(n-M(n))+BL*xh(n);


end;
soundsc(y,fs);
```

It has some errors and i haven't figured out how to mix my original signal with the processed one.
How can i make this work ?

A second try :

```
function y=sine_chorus(x, f_sine, delay, depth, mix, fs);
BL=0.7;
FB=-0.7;
FF=1;
x=wavread(x);

%sound(x,fs);
D=ceil(delay*fs);
xlen=length(x);
y=zeros(size(x));
%filter

for i=D+1:1:xlen
M(i)=delay+depth*(0.5+0.5*sin((2*pi*f_sine*i)/fs));
xh=x(i)+FB*xh(i-M(i));
y(i)=FF*xh(i-M(i))+BL*xh(i);
y(i)=x(i)+mix*x(i-M(i));
end
soundsc(y,16000);
```

Now the y array which is created should have my output signal, instead of this it's filled with zeros.
What's going wrong with this ?

Comment: what kind of error? Please provide input data and expected output.

Comment: Error in chorus (line 9)
    xh=x(n)+FB*xh(n-M(n));
input data will be any .*wav file and the output will be the processed signal

Comment: Error in chorus (line 9) xh=x(n)+FB*xh(n-M(n));

Comment: This is not the full error message...

Comment: Undefined function or variable "xh".

Comment: Well, yeah. _Just as the error says_, `xh` isn't defined when you first use it in calculating a new value for `xh`...

Comment: I could use the matlab editor to see that obvious error, but of course  the problem it's not there.The formulas are mathematicaly correct, the matlab script is the problem.Look my edited one, it hasn't predifined the xh but it works without error.

Comment: @panos_vs_panos Sounds like the loop doesn't run, so not only does `y` not get written to but the `xh` line doesn't get evaluated. Check what values `D` and `xlen` have when you reach the start of the loop.